# python, how to sort tuple or list with case insensitive?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have these two lists and I combine them by zip then I want to sort them but it gives me this result (Ard,Ger,Sla,ard) while I wanted to be (ard,Ard,Ger,Sla). any idea?

```
N = ["ard","Ard","Ger","Sla"]
L = ["7","4","2","3"]
x=zip(N,L)
x.sort()
for i in x:
    print i[0]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass a `key` argument to sort:

```
x.sort(key=lambda (a, b): (a.lower(), b))
```

The output is:

```
Ard
ard
Ger
Sla
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. but I tried a.upper() to give ard,Ard .... but gave same result.

Comment: @jesy2013: The number is smaller, so it'll always sort that way.

Comment: potentially hackish but **disclaimer** - *before morning coffee*: `x.sort(key=lambda (a, b): (a.lower(), cmp(a.lower(), a), b))`